# Adding emphasis inside i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, haml, yaml

I'm currently setting up i18n for an app built in rails.
The whole system is really easy to set up and easy to use.
But there is a point that I couldn't quite figure out the best way to do and also couldn't find any info for on the internet.

Say I have a paragraph that I want to set in i18n but I want one word inside the paragraph to be **emphasised**.

What is the best/recommended way to set up such a thing?

---

Currently I'm using this notation but I don't really like it.

The Haml file:

```
%p
  != t("msg.start")
  em!= t("msg.em")
  != t("msg.end")
```

The en.yml file:

```
en:
  msg:
    start: "Hello there"
    em: "you"
    end: ", how are you doing?"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
en:
  msg: Hello there <em>you</em>, how are you doing?

%p
  = t(:msg).html_safe
```

There's no need to run yourself in circles trying to always use haml tags; it's to help you, not to make things more difficult.

Comment: Thanks hadn't thought of it :)